# Is there a use for function declarations inside functions?

Tags: c++, c, declaration

We can *declare* functions inside functions (I wanted a local variable, but it parses as a function declaration):

```
struct bvalue;
struct bdict {
    bdict(bvalue);
}
struct bvalue {
    explict operator bdict() const;
}
struct metainfo {
    metainfo(bdict);
}
void foo(bvalue v) {
    metainfo mi(bdict(v)); // parses as function declaration
    metainfo mi = bdict(v); // workaround
                            // (this workaround doesn't work in the presence of explicit ctors)
}
```

Are the sole reasons "because it makes the parser simpler" and "because the standard says so", or is there an obscure use for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is really a C question, because this behaviour was inherited directly from C (although it gets much more press in C++ because of the *most vexing parse*).

I suspect the answer (in the context of C, at least) is that this allows you to scope the existence of your function declarations to precisely where they're needed.  Maybe that was useful in the early days of C.  I doubt anyone does that any more, but for the sake of backward compatibility it can't be removed from the language.

Comment: Back then, the global namespace was the only one for functions.  How does it work now?  Does a function declaration that's a single identifier go with its containing function's namespace, or the global one?  Can you declare namespaced functions?

Comment: It is still useful. Because the function prototype is limited to the scope of the function it is declared in, one can refer to external functions and symbols _without_ actually polluting the global namespace (with an `#include`). Consider the situation when one wants to call some function declared in a header file while avoiding its inclusion _and_ allowing external code to include it without conflicts. For _extremely lame_ header file sets (`Windows.h` and family, for example) this is specially useful.

Answer (score 9):

It's useful if you need to use an external function whose name would conflict with an internal (static) function or variable in the current translation unit (source file). For instance (silly but it gets the point across):

```
static int read(int x)
{
    return bar(x);
}

static int foo()
{
    ssize_t read(int, void *, size_t);
    read(0, buf, 1);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, with gcc all I get is an error trying to redefine read in foo.

Comment: You are not expected to use a static function in C++, unnamed namespaces instead. Plus, if that's your excuse to use a function YOU created with "the wrong name" instead of renaming your function... it's really taking a chance.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: This question was tagged both C and C++, and in C it's definitely the correct way. I'll agree this was poor tagging, but I didn't even notice the C++ tag.

Answer (score 3):

A function declaration inside another function hides other overloaded functions. e.g. Compiler error on Line 7

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int);
int main() {

    void f(char *);
    f(10);              // Line 7
    f("Hello world");
    return 0;
}

void f(int a) {
    std::cout << a;
}

void f(char *str) {
    std::cout << str;
}
```

Comment: So calling `f(10)` before new declaration will not give any error?

Answer (score 1):

> Are the sole reasons "because it makes
>   the parser simpler" and "because the
>   standard says so"

Yea, basically.

Everything that can be a function declaration, *is* a function declaration.

Unfortunately it's one of those "just is" cases.

Comment: Apparently, it's useful to fake namespaces in C.

Comment: @Martinho: But that's not why it's so.