# The use of declaring function inside a function?

Tags: c++, function, function-declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a use for function declarations inside functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089452/is-there-a-use-for-function-declarations-inside-functions)

I know that inside function we can declare a function. What is the use of it? Can you please bring a simple example?

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes thanks, I have learnt from this question too. Buy the way it is not the same question. Only the title of question you mentioned coincides with my question. But actually these are different questions.

Comment: seems like the same question to me. Even the answer you picked is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is little value to declaring a function inside a function, unless you intend on defining it later and only having it available to that function- i.e., the function declaration is encapsulated.

```
int main() {
    void foo();
    foo();
}
void some_other_func() {
    foo(); // ERROR
}
void foo() {
}
```

But that's it. In comparison to triggering the Most Vexing Parse, this is an extremely limited benefit at best.

Comment: And this OK for C++! Thanks for an example.

Comment: Banning the declaration of functions inside a function wouldn't solve the most vexing parse problem; the problem also occurs when you attempt to define a variable at namespace scope.  And while declaring a function within another function isn't very useful, there doesn't seem any reason to ban it, and reduce orthogonality.

Comment: Still if you implemented `some_other_func()` AFTER the `foo()` implementation you would have access to `foo()`, so the encapsulation is quite fake.

Comment: Does it mean that there is no real/practical use of declaring function in another function?

Comment: This is a delicate thing, and I need others' opinions as well. I guess it has a real usage DeadMG.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, defining functions inside functions in C/C++ is non-standard and only some compilers support it. However, you can use the new C++ feature, so-called lambda functions.

Defining functions (or lambda functions) inside of other functions can be useful in several ways (depending on the implementation):

1. You keep related code close, it's easier to read and understand.
2. The inner functions may be able to access directly variables of the outer functions (hence, less stuff to pass explicitly as parameters).

Comment: Are you sure about "non-standard"-ness?

Comment: The question is about declaring functions rather than defining them. Inner function *definitions* are non-standard (unless you count C++11 lambdas). Function *declarations* are standard.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Thanks for the clarification. I assumed it was about definition because that's the most useful one here and because people (myself included) tend to mix the two terms and it could be my turn to mix them up. :)

Comment: @Alex: the mix-up isn't helped by the fact that every definition is also a declaration. So when someone says "I've declared this function here" and they've actually defined it, they aren't wrong and the confusion persists...