# Invalid object after elision of copy operation?

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it an error to use an empty set of brackets to call a constructor with no arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no)
>   [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

This one gets me mad. Maybe its just too simple.

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo() {}
  Foo(const Foo& f) {}
  void work() {}
};

int main()
{
  Foo f( Foo() );
  f.work();
}
```

GCC 4.6 gives me:

```
error: request for member ‘work’ in ‘f’, which is of non-class type ‘Foo(Foo (*)())’
```

After elision of the copy operation the effective code might look like:

```
int main()
{
  Foo f;
  f.work();
}
```

But why can't i call `work()` ??

Edit:

Yes, duplicate (see below). Didn't find the original post when search first because the source of the symptoms of this is located where i didn't expect that.

Comment: Why do you write `Foo f( Foo() );` in the first place, what is wrong with writing `Foo f;`, which should work as expected. Your first version creates a completely different type, as you can see in the error message.

Comment: Its of course a bit academic. Comes from a study what constructors are called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Foo f( Foo() );` is a function declaration.

I think you want: `Foo f;`

Or in case you want to copy-construct:

```
Foo f( (Foo()) );
```

Comment: A function declaration is not allowed within a basic block. How can it be interpreted as such?

Comment: @Frank: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work

Comment: and actually you can write something like this inside the funciton: `int bar(int a, int b);`. It will compile

Comment: Yes, seems a function declaration is allowed/accepted by the compiler. Not a definition. All with a basic block

Comment: @Frank: yeah, definition is not allowed

Comment: Thanks, very good and quick answer! You were the first to answer so i give you the mark.

Answer (score 1):

f is effectively a function declaration within main function.
Try

```
Foo f((Foo())); // to make the definition of f explicit enough.
```

Answer (score 1):

n3337 8.2

> The ambiguity arising from the similarity between a function-style
>   cast and a declaration mentioned in 6.8 can also occur in the context
>   of a declaration. In that context, the choice is between a function
>   declaration with a redundant set of parentheses around a parameter
>   name and an object declaration with a function-style cast as the
>   initializer. Just as for the ambiguities mentioned in 6.8, the
>   resolution is to consider any construct that could possibly be a
>   declaration a declaration. [ Note: A declaration can be explicitly
>   disambiguated by a nonfunction-style cast, by an = to indicate
>   initialization or by removing the redundant parentheses around the
>   parameter name. — end note ] [ Example:

```
struct S {
S(int);
};
void foo(double a) {
S w(int(a));
//function declaration
S x(int());
//function declaration
S y((int)a);
//object declaration
S z = int(a);
//object declaration
}
```

> — end example ]

Answer (score 1):

C++ parser interprets `Foo f(Foo());` expression as the function declaration with the signature `Foo(Foo(*)())`, i.e. a function returning Foo and taking a function pointer to the function returning Foo. Adding explicit parenthesis around the argument like so `Foo f((Foo()));` will resolve the ambiguity. But consider actually just doing `Foo f;` which avoids redundant code.

Comment: A function declaration is not allowed within a basic block. How can it be interpreted as such?

Comment: @Frank That is a C legacy [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089452/is-there-a-use-for-function-declarations-inside-functions)