# What does "redefinition" mean?

Tags: c++, redefinition, one-definition-rule

Is it true that redefinition mean that we're trying to define an entity which is already  defined. This question appear from the following code example:

```
int a=5;

int main()
{
    int a=3;//redefinition? I think no, because `int a` denote an entity different from the global "a"
}
```

and one more example:

```
int foo(){ return 1; }

int main()
{
    int foo();
    int a=foo();//Now a is 1
}
```

We can't define just declared `foo()` function inside the `main()` function body, but if we can will it be a redefinition?

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't understand what redefinition does mean. I'm just thinking about it. I'm trying to understand...

Comment: Note that, in C, there's a difference between a *declaration* and a *definition*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local variables might shadow global ones, that's what the `::` scope resolution operator is for

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a=5;

int main()
{
    int a=3;

    cout << a; // 3
    cout << ::a; // 5
}
```

so no [ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) problems here.

As for the second example the function declaration inside another function (when it doesn't get confused by the *most-vexing-parse*), I recommend this question: [Is there a use for function declarations inside functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6089452/1938163)

And: no, **you can't redefine** your function inside main(). You can redeclare it (even with different parameters, thus declaring a new function) but that doesn't mean you can **define** it so.

There's an excellent excerpt from the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule#Summary) which I recommend to read:

> In short, the ODR states that:
>
> - In any translation unit, a template, type, function, or object can
>     have no more than one definition. Some of these can have any number of
>     declarations. A definition provides an instance.
> - In the entire
>     program, an object or non-inline function cannot have more than one
>     definition; if an object or function is used, it must have exactly one
>     definition. You can declare an object or function that is never used,
>     in which case you don't have to provide a definition. In no event can
>     there be more than one definition.
> - Some things, like types, templates,
>     and extern inline functions, can be defined in more than one
>     translation unit. For a given entity, each definition must be the
>     same. Non-extern objects and functions in different translation units
>     are different entities, even if their names and types are the same.
>
> Some violations of the ODR must be diagnosed by the compiler. Other
>   violations, particularly those that span translation units, are not
>   required to be diagnosed.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)

Comment: Did you mean that redefinition is when we're trying to redefine already defined entity?

Comment: ODR = one DEFINITION rule, that means you can't redefine stuff otherwise you'd get duplicate symbols. So yes.

Comment: Many thanks. I tried to understood this concept no one day. Now I've understood. :)

Answer (score 0):

No. `int a = foo();` or `int a = 3;` , inside `main()`, is a new variable that is also called `a`.

A redefinition is an attempt to redefine the same variable, e.g.:

```
int a = 5;
int a = 6;
```

Also

```
int foo();
```

is not a definition. It's a declaration.  A function definition includes `{ }`.

Comment: IT doesn't explain my misunderstanding. Please see my first example where int a redefined into the main().

Answer (score 0):

No, when dealing with redefinition, it is important to remember SCOPE. It only applies for two variables with the same name that are defined in the SAME SCOPE

In example 1, the second a is LOCAL SCOPE and is local to the function. Therefore, that is the a that is viewed and referred to until you exit the function body

Comment: Exactly the opposite. Redefinition has nothing to do with scopes. Scopes deal with declarations of names, definitions deal with entities denoted by names.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is not a redefinition due to different scopes, just like you thought.

The second one is a redeclaration, but it's ok to redeclare something any number of times you want, though the joke gets stale with repetition.

If you allow definition of functions inside functions, you get to write all the semantics, because there ain't such yet (aside from lambdas).
For someone who did so, look at the GCC C compiler, "nested functions" and "statement expressions".

Anyway, redefintion would be an error due to the One Definition Rule.

Answer (score 0):

Redefinition is somewhat what leads to compiler-time error.
For example:

```
int a;
bool a;
```

or

```
void f();
int f;
```

In your case there wasn't compiler-time error. It was about name hiding, scope and resolving rules.

```
int a = 5;
{
  int a = 6; //because of { } internal a is in other scope and can be defined without error
  int b = a; //b == 6
}
int b = a; //b == 5
```

In the last case you have two diffrent "a", each in own scope of program.
In one point of program if you use a name such "a", there is only one entity that is behind this name. If compiler can't find the best match for "a" between diffrent variants you get redifinition and error.

Comment: Your examples are not those of redefinition. They are those of incompatible redeclaration of names. In particular, in no context can the construct `void f();` be definition, it is always a mere declaration.

Comment: You are right. However question was not exactly about redifinition but about name scope misunderstanding.