# How to verify that two nested variants share the same type

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, variadic-templates, variant

The code uses nested `std::variant`s to model messages:

```cpp
class A{};
class B{};
class C{};
class D{};
using CMD1 = std::variant<A, B>;
using CMD2 = std::variant<C, D>;
using CMD = std::variant<cmd1, cmd2>;
```

In order to send the messages to the right actors the actors define a public `typelist` with all the types of the commands they want to receive:

```cpp
struct ActorAC {
  using handleable = typelist<A,C>;
};
struct ActorBD {
  using handleable = typelist<B, D>;
};
```

At runtime the scheduler receives a command - the type is the variant encapsulating all of the other sub-variants, then it checks if the command's **concrete** type is inside the actors' `typelist`, if it is it sends the message to the actor:

```cpp
CMD cmd = get_cmd();
//this is what I'd like to do
if (is_any(get_concrete_type(cmd), actorAC::handleables)){
  // send message to actorAC
}
if (is_any(get_concrete_type(cmd), actorBD::handleables)) {
  //send message to actor BD
}
```

getting the variant's current member is only possible with `visit`, so let's try that, we'll write a function that check if a given type is one of the concrete types of a variant:

```cpp
template <typename HandlableType, typename... Types>
constexpr bool is_concrete(std::variant<Types...> v) {
  return std::visit(Overload{
                        [](HandelableType) {
                          /*it's the same Type! finished*/
                          return true;
                        },
                        []<typename... Typesin>(std::variant<Typesin...> vin) {
                          /* we still didn't get to the leaf variants*/
                          return is_in_concrete<HandlableType>(vin);
                        },
                        [](auto) {
                          /* if it is not a variant and also not our type - for sure it's not what we want*/
                          return false;
                        },
                    },
                    v);
}
```

let's try to use it:

```cpp
int main(){
  CMD cmd(A());
  //should compile and return true
  return is_concrete<A>(cmd);
}
```

but I get this error from g++-13:

> error: no matching function for call to 'is_concrete'

> note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'std::variant<Types...>' against 'std::variant<V1, V2> (*)(A)' (aka 'variant<variant<A, B>, variant<C, D>> (*)(A)')

So at the first call from `main` the compiler doesn't match - what is happening??

ideally in the end it would be:

```cpp
template<typename... tl>
bool shouldActUpon(CMD cmd) {
  return (is_concrete<tl>(cmd) || ...);
}
```

here is the complete file:

```cpp
#include <variant>

template <typename... Ts> struct Overload : Ts... {
  using Ts::operator()...;
};
template <typename... Ts> Overload(Ts...) -> Overload<Ts...>;

class A {};
class B {};
class C {};
class D {};

using V1 = std::variant<A, B>;
using V2 = std::variant<C, D>;
using V = std::variant<V1, V2>;


template <typename HandlableType, typename... Types>
constexpr bool is_concrete(std::variant<Types...> cmd) {
  return std::visit(Overload{
                        [&](HandlableType) {
                          /*v1 is a variant in the index call recursive*/
                          return true;
                        },
                        [&]<typename... Typesin>(std::variant<Typesin...> vin) {
                          return is_concrete<HandlableType>(vin);
                        },
                        [](auto) {
                          /*v1 is not a variant - both are of the same type,
                           * same index, and leaf*/
                          return true;
                        },
                    },
                    cmd);
}

int main() {
  V cmd(A);
  is_concrete<A>(cmd);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expected `main` to return 1, try changing `V cmd(A);` to `V cmd{A{}};`.

---

Indeed, if you look carefully at the error,

```
note: candidate template ignored: could not match
'std::variant<Types...>'
against
'std::variant<V1, V2> (*)(A)' (aka 'variant<variant<A, B>, variant<C, D>> (*)(A)')
```

it's telling you that the compiler can't match the variant against... **a pointer to function with argument of type `A` and return value the variant**.

So you should wonder *"why in the world does the compiler think I'm passing **a pointer to function**"*??

Well, [MVP is the answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse): `V cmd(A);` is the declaration of a function named `cmd` with one argument of type `A` and return type `V`, which has type `V(A)`; when passed around as an argument, that type decays to a **pointer to** funtion etc, i.e. `V(*)(A)`.

Comment: Why in the name of god can we declare functions inside functions  no body uses that

Comment: @EyalKamitchi, I'm reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31597909/why-allow-function-declarations-inside-function-bodies) right now. Maybe the answer is there.