# I can not access elements of a vector in a function after passing the vector to the function as a parameter

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to pass a `cv::Vec3f` vector as parameter to an function, but inside the function I can not access the vector elements.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {

    cv::Vec3f y(1.0f, 5.0f, 2.0f);
    cv::Matx33f M(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
    std::vector<cv::Vec3f> test(const std::vector<cv::Vec3f>&p,const cv::Matx33f &M);
    cv::Vec3f v1_new = test({y}, M)[0];    

    std::cout<<v1_new<<std::endl;

std::vector<cv::Vec3f> test(const std::vector<cv::Vec3f>& p, const cv::Matx33f &M)
{
    std::vector<cv::Vec3f> result;
    return p[0];
}
```

errors:

```
 error: could not convert ‘(& p)->std::vector<cv::Vec<float, 3> >::operator[](0)’ from ‘const value_type {aka const cv::Vec<float, 3>}’ to ‘std::vector<cv::Vec<float, 3> >’
     return p[0];
               ^
```

Comment: Have you read the error messages? It's very clear: *could not convert const cv::Vec<float, 3> to std::vector<cv::Vec<float, 3> >*.

Comment: std::vector<cv::Vec3f> test(const std::vector<cv::Vec3f>&p,const cv::Matx33f &M); whats that line supposed to do? Anyways, please show complete code always

Comment: and my question is how can I access the vector elements in this case?

Comment: @CommodoreYournero it is a function declaration

Comment: how am I converting the element? I just try to return the first element of the vector in that function.

Comment: @RemyLebeau place that in a header file or at the beginning of your file, after includes, never inside another function

Comment: @CommodoreYournero function *declarations* are legal (albeit rare) inside of function *bodies*, they don't need to be in global scope. [Is there a use for function declarations inside functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089452/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ARE accessing the elements. That is not the problem.

The problem is that you are trying to convert an element to an incompatible type. As the error message says:

> could not convert ... ‘const cv::Vec<float, 3>’ to ‘std::vector<cv::Vec<float, 3> >’

Your function wants to return a *vector* of `cv::Vec3f` elements, but you are trying to return a *single* `cv::Vec3f` instead.  That does not match the function's return type, so a conversion has to happen, but there is no such conversion defined, hence the error.

You declared a compatible vector variable, `result`, but you are not filling it with anything, or `return`'ing it.

Try this instead:

```cpp
std::vector<cv::Vec3f> test(const std::vector<cv::Vec3f>& p, const cv::Matx33f &M)
{
    std::vector<cv::Vec3f> result;
    result.push_back(p[0]);
    return result;
}
```